# Как реализовать окна, как уведомления у Facebook?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Как сделать такое окно?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно было просто написать, как на facebook

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) - popovers